# Birthday Celebration on SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Company birthdays can only be celebrated on weekdays.

If someone's birthday falls on a weekday, it is celebrated on that same day.
If their DOB falls on a Saturday or Sunday, the CelebrationDate column should have the date of the next Monday.

How can this be done using a CTE in Microsoft SQL Server Studio?

```
WITH Birthday AS
(
    SELECT
        concat(FirstName, ' ', LastName) AS FullName
        , BirthDate AS Birthdate
    FROM Employee
),
CelebrationDay AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM Employee
    --LOGIC MISSING
)    
SELECT
    FullName
    , FORMAT(Birthdate, 'MM/dd/yyyy') AS BirthDate
FROM Birthday
```

Comment: I'm a little lost on what CTEs have to do with celebrating birthdays.  I've never invited a CTE to a birthday party ;)  Please provide sample data and desired results so it is clear what you want to accomplish.

Comment: Have you looked at this code yet?  https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/T-SQL-How-to-find-Next-39c00e75  It looks like you want to create a case statement and run it against the extracted day of week of birthday.

Answer (score 3):

If the birthday occurs on Sunday, we will need to add one day, if it occurs on Saturday you will need to add two.  No need for a CTE:

```
SET DATEFIRST 7 ;  --Ensures Sunday is day 1
SELECT
  FirstName + ' ' + LastName as FullName
 ,BirthDate
 ,CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,BirthDate) = 1 THEN DATEADD(DAY,1,BirthDate)
    WHEN DATEPART(WEEKDAY,BirthDate) = 7 THEN DATEADD(DAY,2,BirthDate)
    ELSE BirthDate
  END AS CelebrationDate
From
  Employee
```

Comment: I suppose you could get all fancy with Modulus and combine into a single statement but readable code is good code

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DATENAME` function to calculate the day of the birthday and accordingly add days to arrive at celebration dates.

```sql
select CASE WHEN datename(weekday,birthday) = 'Saturday' THEN CAST(dateadd(day,2,birthday) AS DATE)
            WHEN datename(weekday,birthday) = 'Sunday' THEN CAST(dateadd(day,1,birthday) AS DATE)
            ELSE birthday 
            END as CelebrationDay   
FROM
(
VALUES ('2020-07-17'), -- Friday
('2020-07-18'), -- Saturday
('2020-07-19') -- Sunday
) as t(birthday)
```

```
+----------------+
| CelebrationDay |
+----------------+
| 2020-07-17     |
| 2020-07-20     |
| 2020-07-20     |
+----------------+
```